# is it possible to recover the parameters of the PasteSpecial action in excel through vba?

Tags: excel, vba, range, paste

is there a way to "listen' to the PasteSpecial command and its parameters in excel?
I'm writing a vba code to manage the Range.PasteSpecial method and realized I need a way to know if the Transpose parameter of the action defined by the user is true or false, so I can treat the source data accordingly.
Offcourse, since I don't know when Transpose is TRUE, this piece of code below does not really work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim UndoList As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled = True Then

   UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
   MsgBox (UndoList & "!")
     If Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste " Or UndoList = "Paste special" Then
        
        If UndoList = "Paste special" Then
            If Transpose Then
            MsgBox ("Paste Transposed Values")
             Application.EnableEvents = False
             Application.Undo
             Application.EnableEvents = True
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
             'and other stuff
            Exit Sub
            Else
            MsgBox ("Paste Values")
             Application.EnableEvents = False
             Application.Undo
             Application.EnableEvents = True
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
             'and other stuff
            Exit Sub
         End If
         ElseIf Left(UndoList, 5) = "Paste" Then
        MsgBox ("Just Paste formats")
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False

        Exit Sub

     Else
        MsgBox ("choose another method")
         'Application.Undo
     Exit Sub
     End If
Else
Exit Sub
End If
UndoList = ""
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you evaluate the ```Selection``` to see if it has one row or one column to identify if transpose was used?

Comment: Hi @igittr . Yes, it is possible, but I am trying to also anticipate a scenario where the user tranposes a 'square' selection and .Rows.Count and .Col.Count are equal.